# Replace inside a replace in Vim

Tags: vim, replace

How do you replace inside a replace?

I know you can get the current word under the cursor into the replace, but I want to perform a replace on it before having it as the output.

For example:

- Having a document that has passed through the [clbuttic filter](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx) and replacing words that you know have been affected for the worse, such as deinstitutionalization (Hint: Consbreastution of the United States of America). The file also has some words that are properly replaced.
- Changing `o` to `0` in Wooloomooloo (and only for that word) throughout a document

A real world example (from my vim history) is being in a Latex document and running

```
%s/\\begin{table}\[h\]/\\begin{table}\[H\]/c
```

where I am duplicating the string just to get a minor change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing o to 0 is straightforward:

```
:s/o/0/g
```

Perhaps you want to know how to apply it to a (visual) selection?

```
:s/\%Vo/0/g
```

**Edit** Likely what you want (see comments)

```
:%s/\<\zs[Wolm]\+\>\ze/\=substitute(submatch(0), 'o', '0', 'g')/g
```

What this does:

- `[Wolm]\+` matches sequences consisting of just `W`,`o`,`l`,`m`
- `\<[Wolm]\+\>` matches (independent) *words* of the same (so, Wooloomooloo, or `mooW`, `Wlomo` would all match, but not `amool` etc).
- `\zs` marks the begin of the *match* for replace, `\ze` the end
- `\=substitute(submatch(0), 'o', '0', 'g')` replaces the match (between `\zs` and `\ze`) but subsituting `0` for `o`

You can start from this pattern

- replacing `[Wolm]\+` with your actual target
- adding optional context outside `\zs...\ze` so you can reduce matches
- adding `\c` in the front of the pattern to enable case-insensitive matching

Comment: Updated question to clarify. Your suggestions would either replace all `o`s or just replace one instance (unless I am mistaken)

Comment: Ok, so `%s/Wooloomooloo/W00l00m00l00/g` ...?

Comment: @Portablejim: I think I came up with pretty good hints to get you started now, see updated answer + breakdown explanation + tips. Have a look :)

Comment: Not exactly as short/simple as I was hoping for, but still a way to do it. Came across the "command line window with history of commands" that will probably help as well. http://vimcasts.org/episodes/refining-search-patterns-with-the-command-line-window/

Answer (score 0):

Try typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> while you're writing your `:sub` command. This will open the command-line window and allow you to use vim's normal mode to edit your command. If you press Enter in this mode, the current line will be executed. If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>, you'll drop back to the command-line mode with the current line as the current text.

The command-line window is also what happens when you accidentally type `q:`. (I know I did that a lot before understanding what it's for. It also has history of your previous commands. Also try the same during a `/` search or type `q/`.

See also `:help cmdline-window`